# Using AVG & IIF to return the average paid for a specfic fee code

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am taking a stab at a report that is fairly difficult for me - so be patient with the newbie.   I am looking to get an average amount of each feetype (the designated column is CODE) charged on each permit type issued.   The Expression I have written -- in many forms -- follows.

```
 =AVG(IIF(Fields!CODE.Value="CODE-PERMIT",Fields!PAID_AMOUNT.Value),"FEES")
```

FEES is the dataset.   I have also used the Tablix and the Group as the scope.

I know I am missing something important because I get this error:

> The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘Textbox582.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ has a scope parameter that is
>   not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set
>   to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing
>   group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=AVG(IIF(Fields!CODE.Value="CODE-PERMIT",Fields!PAID_AMOUNT.Value,Nothing),"FEES")
```

Note `IIF()` function takes three arguments.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Well, I am no longer getting the error (thank you so much) but with the Nothing "argument" tablix textbox is empty when I run the report.   I changed it to 0 and then 1 and all 0's and 1's were returned in the textbox.    What is that place telling the expression?

Comment: The nothing argument is passed when `Fields!CODE.Value` is different to `CODE-PERMIT` so AVG function calculates average for `CODE-PERMIT` only for not null (nothing) values. Edit your qustion to include a sample of your data and the expected results if you need further help.

Comment: I am happy to report that I just had a simple typo in it so it works great.   Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If my answer solved your issue you can select it as the correct answer or upvote it. [How to select an answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)